# When can we daven for a neis? 

Tags: chanuka, riddle, hashkafah-philosophy

Riddle version of the question: When can we daven for a neis

Hashkafic version of the question: Why does it seem that we can daven for a neis, when this is explicitly forbidden in masechet Brachot?

Comment: This seems genuinely to be two questions, the second of which is predicated on the answer to the first. Why not post as such?

Comment: Re your second question: Where exactly in Berachos is this, anyway? There's the saying that "one should not stand in a dangerous place and expect a miracle...," but that's not the same thing as praying for one. (Also, that's not in Berachos.)

Answer (score 5):

That's not the only place. In some siddurim you can find a tefillah to be said at the end of Birkas Kohanim, beginning Yehi Ratzon. Part of the text there is:

> ותעשה עמי נפלאות ונסים, ולטובה אות
>
> "Do for me wonders and miracles, and a
>   sign for good."

Answer (score 4):

If one forgets "al hanisim" in bentching, one may insert the following tefilla:
HARACHAMAN HU YA'ASEH LANU NISIM V'NIFLA'OT KA'ASHER ASAH LA'AVOTEINU BAYAMIM HAHEIM BIZMAN HAZEH. BIMEI MATITYAHU...